# County list of Woodard's American Nations

Tags: geospatial, county

I've been looking for a list of counties in each "nation" of Woodard's map of American Nations. However, I only found maps of it and certainly as a beginner in the field, I am unable to transform this map into tabular list of counties in each "nations". I've checked his website but latest comment from visitors in his post about American Nations was 3 years ago.

I'm wondering if anyone have the list of counties for Woodard's American Nations or if there's any cultural map similar to Woodard's that's as defensible as Woodard's.

[image]http://www.colinwoodard.com/files/ColinWoodard_AmericanNations_map.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generated [a table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16P_67njn5zN_YJzYM_khkg9iW17NkromSIz1BfpV09o/edit?usp=sharing) of US counties categorized by Woodard's American Nations as shown on that map. Here's how I made it:

1. Downloaded [US county polygons shapefile](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-current-county-and-equivalent-national-shapefile) from data.gov
2. Georeferenced the Woodard's American Nations pdf in QGIS
3. Manually selected the county polygons that overlapped each "American Nations" region, and added that information to the attribute table.
4. Joined the county file to a [state boundary file](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2017.html) to add state names to the table. (Because the county file only had "STATEFP" numerical codes instead of state names.)
5. Exported county names, state names, and "american nation" names into a single table.

Note that this table only includes US counties. The "nations" boundaries on the Canadian portion of the map don't correspond with county boundaries. The boundaries on the Mexican portion of the map correspond to states, not counties. The Mexican states of Baja California, Sonora, Chihuahua, Coahuila, Nuevo Leon and Tamaulipas are part of the "EL NORTE" region.

Comment: WOW thank you so much!!! and I just found out about QGIS btw thank you for that too!

Comment: Thank you so much for doing all this hard work! One question, though: I don't see any counties listed as "New Netherlands." Woodard's map suggests the five boroughs of New York City + Bergen County in New Jersey would likely be among those. These all show up in your table as "Yankeedom," but I'm not sure if that's correct.